# Flask Google Maps Infobox with multiple marker images leads to wrong information

Tags: python, google-maps, flask

I have a Flask application where user can search for a room in a city by typing in the cityname.

When a cityname is typed in the user is redirected to a result page, where I use flask google maps to show available rooms on the map with markers.

I have two different marker images (for free users and for users who paid):

```
mymap.markers['static/img/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-small.png'] = markerlist
mymap.markers['static/img/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Pink.png'] = markerlist_bezahlt
```

I populate the markers with a list, where all other informations are stored, f.e. the room and the rooms image, plus it is clickable and redirects on click to the details page.

Here is the whole method which creates the map and the markers depending on whether user has payed or is free (findroomcity is the cityname which a searching user has typed in):

```
location = geolocator.geocode(findroomcity)

    if location.latitude is not None:
        mymap = Map(
        identifier="view-side",
        lat=location.latitude,
        lng=location.longitude,
        infobox=[],
        markers=[],
        zoom = 12
        )
    else:
        print "location is none"


    all_users = User.query.order_by(desc('bezahlt')).all()


    markerlist = []
    markerlist_bezahlt = []


    for room in all_rooms_in_city:
        if room.stadt == findroomcity.lower():
            try:
                location2 = geolocator.geocode(room.stadt + " " + room.strasse + " " + room.hausnr, timeout=2)
                for user in all_users:
                    if user.id == room.users_id:
                        if user.bezahlt == False:
                            markerlist.append((location2.latitude, location2.longitude))
                            mymap.infobox.append(r'''<a href='/details/''' + str(room.id) + "'>" +  r'''<img class='marker-img' src='../static/userimg/''' + room.hauptbild + "'/>")
                        else:
                            markerlist_bezahlt.append((location2.latitude, location2.longitude))
                            mymap.infobox.append(r'''<a href='/details/''' + str(room.id) + "'>" +  r'''<img class='marker-img' src='../static/userimg/''' + room.hauptbild + "'/>")

            except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
                print "in der schleife timeout", e  
            except AttributeError as e:
                print "in der schleife attributeerror", e   

    mymap.markers['static/img/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-small.png'] = markerlist
    mymap.markers['static/img/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Pink.png'] = markerlist_bezahlt
```

The problem is that some markers have the wrong information stored. I guess it is because I am splitting into two markers?

Here is a life example  from heroku:
[Heroku for testing](http://monteurzimmer-1a.herokuapp.com/)

Search for "Dortmund" and check the two small blue markers (these are both "FREEUSERZIMMER") but one of them shows a payed room

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess— but from looking at the source code of your search page showing the markers I can see duplicates of `var marker_0` and others.  I presume you're iterating through the `markerlist` from a zero index, then the `markerlist_bezahlt` basing their `marker_x` names off their index location, so the second list overrides the data for the first markers.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what happens, I have a better understanding now, actually both of them are wrong. But how to prevent it? infobox should work for two different markers or?